# Connection refused telnet localhost 8080

Tags: centos, telnet

I am running a CentOS 7 machine and when I try to telnet localhost 8080 I get the following message

```
Trying ::1...
Telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Telnet: conenct to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

I have added 8080/tcp to the IP table and have opened the port. Any idea what is stopping it?

Comment: are you sure that something is actually listening at that port? You can check that typing `netstat -lntu | grep 8080`

Comment: @Esse when I do this, nothing appears. But when I do it for port 22 for example, it is listening. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: remove 8080 port from your telnet command..Use `telnet localhost`. telnet always works on port 22 by default.

Comment: @GoinOff when I do this, the connection is also refused

Comment: I don't know to which service you're trying to connect but it isn't turned on.

Comment: Try using SSH instead of telnet. `ssh localhost`

Comment: If you need telnet, view `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet` file and check out the `disable = no` property.

Comment: @GoinOff I have checked for this file and it doesn't seem to exist on this system

Comment: Might want to check out this doc http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/12/08/install-telnet-server-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's simple: port 8080 is not opened, just like @Esse told you.

You can check the connection with echo also:

```
echo OK > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080
echo $?
```

You can list opened ports using netstat:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

## Edit:

You can test that the port is not opened by trying to open the port yourself:

```
# open port 8080 using netcat
nc -l 8080 &
# check connection
netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
telnet localhost 8080
echo OK > /dev/tcp/$(hostname -f)/8080
nc 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Comment: It is saying connection refused when I do this. Any idea on how to open this port?

Comment: `nc -l 8080` got stuck?

Comment: I used `nc -v -l 8080` and got `8080: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
listening on [any] 44613 ...`

Answer (score 0):

same
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include how this answers the original question? As it stands, it's hard to understand your answer.